# What's the difference between `listoftablesname` and `listtablename`?

Tags: table-of-contents

I've found templates with `listoftablesname` and others with `listtablename`. Are they used by different packages? Or is one of them an old version of the same variable?

Comment: Can you give an example of a template using both variables?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean a single template using both. I mean that I can find both of them in (different) templates. As I mix templates in my document, I don't know the relevance of each one of them. I'm gonna change the text.

Comment: \listtablename is a macro defined by most document classes as "List of Tables" and translated into many languages by packages like babel.  I couldn't find listoftablesname in any of the packages I have loaded.  It could be a construct using `\csname listof#1name\endcsname`